# crystal report showing duplicate records

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005, crystal-reports

i have a student table , i want to show the Student Name as a heading , and then his/her details in a whole row, but the report is showing every student record twice. how to do this? i have added the Student Name and all the columns in the Detail Section.

These are the columns from the Student table:

**StudentName | Class|  section| Course| DOB**

I want that the display is like this:

----------------------**Student1 Name**  ---this would be the heading

Class|  section| Course| DOB**

----------------------**Student 2 Name**  ---this would be the heading

Class|  section| Course| DOB**

----------------------**Student 3 Name**  ---this would be the heading

Class|  section| Course| DOB**

Comment: What is the query used to populate the report? Did you test it's output?

Comment: @Bogdan0x400: how do i know the query? i have used the wizard? can you please tell how to know the query? also , please guide me to some books where i could find creating Crystal Reports programmatically and not by wizards

Comment: I don't remember any books, but you can definitely look up the SQL of the generated request. I can't send a screenshot because I don't have Crystal Reports on my computer right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the "group by" option (Menu Insert\Group), choose studentName field as group by field. Delete the studentName field from your detail\header lines, and it will then appear as requested